# Best way to debug Java stream() NullPointerException Cause

Tags: javascript, java, rest, stream, resttemplate

In Java, I have the following code:

```
return new RestTemplate().getForObject("https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=finger", CollectionWrapper.class)
    .getCollection()
    .getItems().stream()
    .map(Item::getLinks)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .filter(link-> "preview".equals(link.getRel()))
    .map(Link::getHref)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It throws a NullPointerException with the following error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at [... MyController.java]
```

### My Question

What's the best/easiest/fastest way to debug the cause for this NPE using common tools of a Java developer ?

### My best solution (so far)

Rewrite the code in JavaScript and run it in any Browser DevTools JS Console

```
fetch("https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=finger").then(data => data.json()).then(data => {
    const result = data
        .collection
        .items
        .map(item => item.links)
        .flat()
        .filter(link => link.rel === "preview")
        .map(link => link.href)

    console.log(result)
})
```

In Chrome's JS Console, this gives me

```
VM704:7 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'rel' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:7:22
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:7:2
```

In other words, I'm trying to access the "rel" property of a missing "link" item inside my filter(). If I first filter out all "item" elements that don't have "links", my code runs without Exceptions both in Java and in JavaScript.

But how to quickly find this cause without duplicating and running the code in JavaScript ?

Answer (score 1):

In general You can use the `peek()` method to print or perform some debugging on the stream. It works similarly to the `foreach`, but it returns the `Stream` instead of   `void`. But really, anytime You are trying to access the element of the list You should assert that the list is not empty, in Your case You could use `filter()` to filter empty lists.

Comment: I didn't know peek(). Thank You. Do you have a concrete idea how it could be used in a helpful way for debugging a situation like the one I described above ?

Comment: Well, I think the NPE in Your case comes from this line       
`  .filter(link => link.rel === "preview")`. It's most certainly because the link was null. So You could add `peek()` that would print any elements that are null.

Comment: Sorry to be so dense, but could you give me an example of how I could use peek() to print elements that are null?